# Xcode Build error Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GameScene"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6.1, arm64, chartboost

I have activated arm7 armv7 arm64 as valid architecture for 64 bit requirement by Apple recently but when I try to build the app in Xcode it throws me this error. I get a warning first for `libchartboost.a` not being found, I download the chartboost latest folder from their website but it does not have `libchartboost.a` so I am still using chartboost 3.2.1. But not sure if thats the issue since I get an error related to GameScene below. Am I missing a framework? Thanks for your help.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Administrator/Documents/Software/libChartboost.a, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/Administrator/Documents/Software/libChartboost.a (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GameScene", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AlertLayer.o
      objc-class-ref in GameLayer.o
      objc-class-ref in levelpackMenuLayer.o
      objc-class-ref in LevelSelectLayer.o
      objc-class-ref in timetrialMenuLayer.o
      objc-class-ref in IAPHelper.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Probably libChartboost.a doesn't have support for arm64. Have you tried with the latest one?

Comment: I downloaded the chartboost latest SDK from their website but I could not locate libchartboost.a file in there. Any idea where I can get the latest file for libchartboost.a? All it comes with is .framework and headers files. Thanks for your time.

Comment: https://github.com/aajiwani/EasyNDK-for-cocos2dx/tree/master/Chartboost%20iOS%20Sample%20Project/SampleNDK/Chartboost

Comment: So I already am referencing Chartboost3.2.1 but that does not seem to work. I also downloaded 5.1.3 from this link but sure enough I cannot find libchartboost.a anywhere :( https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/201219435-iOS-SDK-Download

Answer (score 0):

Probably an old thread, but in such linker errors, following step works:

Link all the required frameworks along with Chartboost framework, such as `Storekit`, `Webkit`, `AVFoundation`, `Foundation` etc.

These are all the frameworks that are used by Chartboost framework to fetch and display ads in media formats (audio and video).

For latest details on how to fully integrate and what all frameworks are required, [refer to this guide](https://answers.chartboost.com/en-us/child_article/ios).